# my css of update page not loading correctly but other page are working very fine

Tags: css, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

When I try to render template passing argument with primary key or `ID` CSS not loading as expected but when I try to render it simply with a request without passing id `arg` it loads perfectly.

viewsy.py

```
def update_lead(request,pk):
    leads = Lead.objects.get(id = pk)
    followup = Followup.objects.all
    agent = Agent.objects.all
    source = Source.objects.all
    print(f"the leads are {leads}")
    context = {"lead":leads,"followup":followup,"agent":agent,"source":source}
    
    return render(request,"home/update_lead.html",context)
```

This is how looks at the frontend when I try passing id with my view it is not loading the css which is expepcted
[image]

it is showing error
[image]

but if we just remove the use of pk then the css will be loading

and it is supposed to look like
[image]

here is my templates code

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block body %}
<div class="container">
  <h2>Create Lead</h2>
  <form action="creat_handle_lead" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="inputEmail4">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail4" required name="name" value="{{lead.name}}">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="inputPassword4">Subject</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputPassword4" name="subject" required value="{{lead.subject}}">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="inputAddress">Email</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputAddress" name="email" placeholder="abc@email.com" value="{{lead.email}}">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="inputAddress2">Contact Number</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="inputAddress2" name="number"value = "{{lead.number}}" placeholder="99XX80XXXX">
      </div>
    </div>
    
    
    <div class="form-row">
      
      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label for="inputState">Source</label>
        <select id="inputState" class="form-control" name="source">
          {% for x in source %}
          <option value="{{x.name}}">{{x.name}}</option>
          <!-- <option selected></option> -->
          {% endfor %}
          
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label for="inputState">Assign To</label>
        <select id="inputState" class="form-control" name="assign">
          {% for x in agent %}
          <option value="{{x.name}}">{{x.name}}</option>
          <!-- <option selected></option> -->
          {% endfor %}
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Initial Followup</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3" name="followup"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update Lead </button>
  </form>
</div>

{% endblock body %}
```

Here is my base.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="../static/elegant/vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="../static/elegant/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i"
        rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template-->
    <link href="../static/elegant/css/sb-admin-2.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>{% block title %}   {% endblock title %}</title>
    {% block exhead %}

    {% endblock exhead %}
</head>
<body>
    
    
    {% block body %}
    

    {% endblock body %}


        <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript-->
        <script src="../static/elegant/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../static/elegant/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    
        <!-- Core plugin JavaScript-->
        <script src="../static/elegant/vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
    
        <!-- Custom scripts for all pages-->
        <script src="../static/elegant/js/sb-admin-2.min.js"></script>
    
        <!-- Page level plugins -->
        <script src="../static/elegant/vendor/chart.js/Chart.min.js"></script>
    
        <!-- Page level custom scripts -->
        <script src="../static/elegant/js/demo/chart-area-demo.js"></script>
        <script src="../static/elegant/js/demo/chart-pie-demo.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You never pass you context to the template engine. It should be `render(request,"home/update_lead.html", context)`. Furthermore you define `context` twice.

Comment: I am sorry sir there was no issue actually i was debugging and i try to remove the context  so that it might work . now i have updated the question correctly

Comment: did you restart the Django server, and use Ctrl+Shift+F5 when visiting the view?

Comment: Yes i did every thing even restart the computer... if you dont mind sir can i show my problem on google meet

Comment: can you show the part of the template where you load the .css/.js files?

Comment: if i give id to the function css not load if i remove id css will load

Comment: can you please [edit] the question where you load the `.css`/`.js` items.

Comment: yes sir i have edited kindly check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237163/discussion-between-sarangkkl-and-willem-van-onsem).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are loading the *static* files with:

```
<script src="../static/elegant/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If the URL looks like `leads/52`, then it will load from `leads/static/elegant/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js` which is not what we are looking for. This originates from the fact that `..` moves one level up, so if we work with `foo/bar/`, then starting with `..` will result in `foo/static/elegant/…`. But if the path is `foo/bar/qux`, it will thus aim to load data with `foo/bar/static/elegant/…` as path.

You can work with an absolute path, and thus implement this as:

```
<script src=/static/elegant/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

or even better, make use of the [**`{% static … %}`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#static) template tag:

```
<script src={% static 'elegant/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
```

It will then prepend the parameter with the value of the [**`STATIC_URL`** setting [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#static-url), which makes it easy to later change the static URL.

You will need to update all the items with a `../static/` prefix.

Comment: why my css working for other page and this page also work if i remove the pk use i know i have not used the standard way of using css but i dont think this might be the reason

Comment: @sarangkkl: it works on other pages, if the URL is only *one level* deep, since the `../` will move one level up. If you thus load a page with as URL `about/`, it will import `static/elegant/...` since it moved to the parent, and then loaded the `static/` subpath. If you however have  a URL with *two* (or more) levels deep, it will only move *one* level up.

Comment: I AM VERY THANKFUL TO YOU SIR THIS IS WORKING NOW